# store `cat` output as a placeholder

Tags: bash, pipe, cat, bioinformatics

I am using a program called [minimap](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2) for aligning reads to a reference genome (computational biology problem). This program requires as input two files as positional arguments: first a reference in `.fasta` format followed by a file with reads, in `fastq`format.

The thing is that I have multiple `fastq` files. One option is to first concatenate them all with `cat *.fastq > cat_all.fastq` then call `minimap`. But I would like to concatenate them all and pipe this file to `minimap`, without saving it to `cat_all.fastq`, so that I don't waste storage space.

Is there a way I can store the `cat` output as a placeholder (without saving it) then pipe to `minimap`, something like?

```
cat *.fastq | minimap2 -ax map-ont /path/to/a/file.fasta {placeholder_for_the_cat_command} > output_file.sam
```

Below is an example of how I call `minimap` on a single (concatenated) file called `PD180425_cat_all.fastq`:

```
minimap2 -ax map-ont /path/to/a/file.fasta PD180425_cat_all.fastq > PD180425_aligned_minimap.sam
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the `bash` shell you may use a *process substitution*:

```
minimap -ax map-ont /path/to/fasta.file <( cat *.fastq ) >output.sam
```

The `<( ... )` is a process substitution.  It will be replaced by the pathname of a named pipe (something like `/dev/fd/XXX`) that will produce the output of the command within when reading from it.  The output of the command in the process substitution is not stored on disk.

As long as the `minimap` tool does not need to jump back and forth in the fastq data, but just reads it sequentially, this will probably work.

Doing this without process substitutions (this would also work with `sh` or any POSIX shell):

```sh
mkfifo fastq_data
cat *.fastq >fastq_data &
minimap -ax map-ont /path/to/fasta.file fastq_data >output.sam
rm fastq_data
```

This does pretty much the same thing as the first command.  It creates a named pipe and concatenates the fastq data to it (the `cat` is running as a background job until all its output has been read by `minimap`, and then terminates).  The `minimap` tool is then invoked with the named pipe for the fastq data.  When done, the named pipe is removed.

Reading from the `fastq_data` pipe means reading directly from the `cat` command, not from some temporary file.  Again, the result of the `cat` is never stored on disk.

If the `minimap` tool for some reason needs a fastq file with a particular filename suffix, this may be the best option.  Just name your named pipe as `data.fastq` or similar.